# Modify a program to accept an email address where the output will be sent

Tags: perl, email, unix

I am developing a Perl script which should take an email address as a parameter. The entire output of the script should be sent to that address as well as printed in screen. Any suggestions?

```
./script -mail xyz@gmail.com
```

Actually I already have a script which is currently printing information about memory utilization of instances, logging information etc. I need to add functionality to that script so that the output is mailed to the address provided as a parameter.

The output is something like

```
memory: 234.3 MB CPU: ...
```

and other stats. I want to run my script like

```
./script -mail xyz@gmail.com
```

and send all output to this email address as well as displaying it on screen.

Comment: You could pipe it to a mail command... your question is way too vague.

Comment: Actually I need my output to be printed on the screen as well as mailed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code so we can point you in the right direction

Comment: Actually I have a script which is currently printing a lot of information about memory utilization of instances, logging information etc. Now, I just need to add a functionality to my script so as to be able to send all the output that is currently being printed as an email in which the one running the script provides an email id.

Output is something like: memory: 234.3 MB CPU:... and other stats.

I want to run my script like: ./script -mail xyz@gmail.com
and hence send all output on screen to this email id also.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code, Stack Overflow is probably not the best place for your question.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us what you have tried so far, so don't expect anyone to give you too much help. But here are a couple of pointers.

- If you are having problems defining and parsing command line options (like `--mail`) then see the standard Perl module [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long).
- If you're having trouble creating and sending email then see the CPAN modules [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) or [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer).